# How does the Easy Victory cheat get data from another app in real time?

Tags: android, java, cheat-engine

Easy Victory was developed in Java for Android

I was very curious about how Easy Victory takes data from the game's balls and billiard cue force/velocity to calculate trajectories

This is not a mod because Easy Victory is not the modified 8 Ball Pool

Somehow it reads data from the game table in real time

It runs in the background and runs the game if the game is installed on the smartphone. Otherwise it redirects to the Play Store to download

How was that possible?

I used Apktool and Ghidra to decompile but I couldn't identify where the cheat actually gets the game information

[image]

Comment: Does the app ask for accessibility settings? Those can directly read the screen.

Comment: A non-rooted Android system uses sandboxes for each app so direct manipulation of the game is unlikely. But there techniques exist where you load a third party apk file (e.g. 8 Ball Pool) into a running app instance (e.g. Easy Victory). In such a case the whole app runs in the same sandbox as easy victory does so direct memory access is possible. If 8 Ball Pool has settings or a high score table those values should be different to the values you see when directly start 8 Ball Pool vs when you start it in easy victory.

Comment: @AndrewT. I haven't tested it (I don't trust it to be anti-ban), I only watch videos and there are no accessibility settings there

Comment: @Robert complex :(